# Does committing transaction close session?

Tags: hibernate, session, transactions

I am new to hibernate.

Does `session.getTransaction().commit()`, close the session? Because in the api documentation it is not mentioned that it closes the session.

In my code I have

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

But I get following exception

> org.hibernate.SessionException: Session was already closed

If I remove `session.close()`, then I do not get this exception.

Answer (score 3):

You can find more info about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040761/control-the-hibernate-sessionwhen-to-close-it-manually). Basically, this depends on how you obtained the session and what is performed in `session.getTransaction().commit();` (transaction lifecycle listeners may close session here if some framework you use registered them, for example).

To check when it is really closed, you can try to set a breakpoint in `AbstractSessionImpl.setClosed` method.