# issue with hibernate "session is closed"

Tags: java, hibernate

I can't save all rows from my file Excel in database, because i get this error :

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!

My code :

```
    AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    conf.addAnnotatedClass(Etudiant.class);
    conf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    new SchemaExport(conf).create(true, true);
    SessionFactory factory = conf.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    for(int i=3;i<tab.length;i++){
        session.beginTransaction();

        etudiant.setNom(tab[i]);
        i++;
        etudiant.setPrenom(tab[i]);
        i++;
        etudiant.setAge(tab[i]);

        session.save(etudiant);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Anyone have an idea plz ?

Comment: I found à solution, but if there is à better solution, it will be welcome: `for(int i=3;i<tab.length;i++){
   session = factory.getCurrentSession();
   session.beginTransaction();

   etudiant.setNom(tab[i]);
   i++;
   etudiant.setPrenom(tab[i]);
   i++;
   etudiant.setAge(tab[i]);
   session.save(etudiant);
   session.getTransaction().commit();
  }`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040761/control-the-hibernate-sessionwhen-to-close-it-manually) post might be helpful. `Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();` gives you a session that is being automatically closed once the transaction is commited (or rolledback).

Answer (score 0):

You are fulling up your first level cache. Clearing and flushing the cache periodically  should be considered when your are doing a bulk insert. Also committing in each iteration slow down the insertion.

You have to do something like this..

```
13.1. Batch inserts

When making new objects persistent flush() and then clear() the sessionregularly in order to control the size of the first-level cache.



 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
session.save(customer);
if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
    //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
  }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: when i proceed like that, i still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a Session with factory.openSession() before you can use the current Session.