# How to check wether session was opened manually or not?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, try-catch

The point of my question is to find the way to determine whether session openned or uses current context. Is there a way to find if I used `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`
or `sessionFactory.openSession()` to get my Hibernate Session object? something like:
`if used current session do nothing else close session manually`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control the hibernate session(when to close it manually)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040761/control-the-hibernate-sessionwhen-to-close-it-manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not closing the session can cause memory leaks and that's independent from usage. That's why it's a good habit to use try-with-resource or put something like:

```
if(session != null) session.close();
```

in `finally` clause.